# What is the Causes and Results of Charcot Foot for Diabetics?

Tags: diabetes, type-1-diabetes, feet, amputation

**Charcot** Foot *Disease* is an affliction in a small percentage of, typically long-term diabetic patients, that is not well understood.

What causes it beyond just being diabetic?

What I have Found: Charcot has no really understood causes other than being Diabetic. There seems to be an indication of Long-Term Diabetes combined with excessive use.  Walking a couple miles when it is not normal might prove to be a trigger.  Personal Experience was 20+ years of poorly controlled diabetes and a day of walking about 3-4 miles.  The ankle swelled badly and then a couple weeks later the foot collapsed going flat, having no arch anymore.

External Link To WebMD - (The notes here are thin though)
https://www.webmd.com/diabetes/what-is-charcot-foot#1-1

Comment: Welcome Aggie. We deal with one clearly focused question per post. Users are required to show their prior research when posting. Please [edit] to narrow it down and show what you searched, found and didn't understand. You can ask subsequent questions in their own threads.